# Как обработать миграцию в Realm?

Tags: android, realm

Есть бд с колонками `_id`, `description`, `sum`. В колонке `sum` лежат значения типа +50, -111, +160, -10. В новой версии бд хочу поменять структуру, чтобы в `sum` лежали просто числа, а знаки были в отдельной колонке: плюс или минус. Как мне это сделать, чтобы у пользователей ничего не удалилось? К сожалению, код не могу показать, от компьютера далеко.

Comment: Перед миграцией сохраните все куда-нибудь, потом заново раскидайте. Сам не пробовал, но думаю это удобно сделать прямо в классе миграции.

Comment: Только может лучше оставить одно поле и хранить их как обычные числа, без плюсов? Мне кажется, плюс проще подставить при выводе числа на экране.